# Selenium SendKeys works only on one textbox in the page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

This code is working:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.ebay.com/sch/ebayadvsearch");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#_nkw")).sendKeys("guitar");
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

And this code is not:

```
Select sc = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#s0-1-17-4[0]-7[3]-_sacat")));
sc.selectByVisibleText("Musical Instruments & Gear");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#s0-1-17-5[2]-@range-comp[]-@range-textbox[]-textbox")).sendKeys("50");
```

I am using Selenium and cssSelectors to automatically fill fields.
The value 'guitar' shows in "Enter keywords or item number".
I expect to see "50" in the min price, and "Musical Instruments & Gear" in "this category".
Don't show up.

Comment: The `#` sign is generally indicative of id in html/css. Have you tried `By.id` when selecting the second element?

Answer (score 0):

looks like there might be an issue with the CSS selector for the input field where you are trying to enter the value "50".

instead of using the CSS selector "#s0-1-17-5[2]-@range-comp[]-@range-textbox[]-textbox", try using a different selector such as the id of the input field or its name attribute.

example:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("s0-1-17-5[2]-@range-comp[]-@range-textbox[]-textbox")).sendKeys("50");
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.name("MinPrice")).sendKeys("50");
```

and the issue with selecting the category, try using a different selector for the dropdown menu. you can try using the ID or the name attribute of the select element.

example:

```
Select sc = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("e1-1")));
sc.selectByVisibleText("Musical Instruments & Gear");
```

or

```
Select sc = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("_sacat")));
sc.selectByVisibleText("Musical Instruments & Gear");
```